# To get IP Address from interface name in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, porting, windows-networking

I like to know, winapi from which i can get ipaddress using interface name. The Linux version of which is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
int main()
{
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char iface[] = "eth0";
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    //Type of address to retrieve - IPv4 IP address
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    //Copy the interface name in the ifreq structure
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name , iface , IFNAMSIZ-1);
    ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
    close(fd);
    //display result
    printf("%s - %s\n" , iface , inet_ntoa(( (struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr) );
    return 0;
}
```

I am looking similar functionality ( as code above) but **for windows in C++**.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can tweak it to your needs...

http://kodeyard.blogspot.in/2009/09/get-ip-address-in-cwindows.html

Comment: with gethostbyname(..), how would you get to know for which interface ip address i am interested in? i guess, this won't do.

Answer (score 1):

See sample of GetAdaptersAddresses function. FriendlyName and FirstUnicastAddress are fields you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

See also: [Get network interface name from IPv4 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288908/get-network-interface-name-from-ipv4-address)

Answer (score 0):

SIGAR is a cross-platform library for getting system info (CPU, RAM, DISK, and Network).  It will allow you to list all network interfaces on Mac / Windows / Linux and get any other info you may need.

http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home

If you don't want to use the whole library, I am sure you could inspect the code to find just the piece you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize WinSock first, and only then use gethostname, gethostbyname and inet_ntoa functions. The following [link](http://suite101.com/article/socket-programming-gethostbyname-a19557) will help you.