# Information about Network Discovery API's

Tags: winapi, networking, discovery

I'm quite new to windows sdk programming and i'm trying to write a code to discover devices on the network. The code should be able to get the name of the device(hostname) and ipadress of the device. Are there any predefinded Api's to do the same. I googled and got certain api's such as

```
 WNetGetNetworkInformation
 WNetGetResourceInformation
```

which didn't seem to serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288908/get-network-interface-name-from-ipv4-address) -- from today!

It shows how you can retrieve all information for a network adapter.

Comment: Thanks Edward , that kind of helped me .